# SQL using Case to convert data types

Tags: sql, case, type-conversion

I am trying to sum the total amount of all payments made, when I do so the answer is given in scientific notation instead of a float with a specific number of decimal places. The column I am concerned with is total_amount, If you could please tell me the proper way to do this and a little background on the Case function that would be great.

```
Select customer.customer_id, customer.email, count(payment.payment_date) as payments_count,
round(sum(Cast(payment.amount as numeric(4,2))), 2)  as total_amount 
From customer join payment 
on customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
group by customer.customer_id
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Looks like MySQL

Comment: Your round and cast should already be giving you 2 decimal places.  What output do you actually want.  By the way, you are selecting non aggregate columns with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Actually, Postgres also supports the `GROUP BY` in this case, as does ANSI SQL -- assuming that `customer_id` is unique/primary key.

Answer (score 0):

`round()` doesn't change the data type, just the value.  Instead, cast *after* doing the `sum()`:

```
Select c.customer_id, c.email, count(p.payment_date) as payments_count,
       Cast(sum(p.amount) as numeric(4, 2))  as total_amount 
From customer c join
     payment p
     on c.customer_id = p.customer_id
group by c.customer_id;
```